# network connectivity issue on google play console

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I am trying to access an app i uploaded on play store through google play console on windows and every time there is network issue. I cleared the cached files and cookies. i restarted everything.It's still not working on any browser(chrome, Firefox, int Exp). I tried on an emulator and my phone and it's working there. But 
i want to access it on my computer.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error message that appears on the browser console? Open it by typing: C+S+i

Comment: stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=3&tid=UA-6194246-1&cid=948871793.1526285601&jid=1934773044&_gid=256550639.1526285601&gjid=1966546376&_v=j67&z=281343906:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
www.gstatic.com/feedback/session_load.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
www.gstatic.com/feedback/js/mt7xzg45d0om/chat_load.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You're behind a proxy on the computer network maybe? Has any extension as adblock enabled? Maybe trying on another network/computer. Or updating your browser.

Comment: i am not using any proxy server and i have already removed all extension. Browser is updated. I did manage to access the website using the same computer through an android emulator though.But i still want to access it on windows using chrome.

Comment: Maybe google is doing something per user agent. You might try changing the user-agent to a Android one using a extension like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg).